# Are there any clients that allow for multiple wallets and API acccess?

Tags: bitcoind, api, multibit

I know that `multibit` has the capacity to have multiple wallets, but no API access. `bitcoind` has great API access, but only one wallet. Is there any solution that combines the two?

Answer (score 3):

- [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/) supports multiple wallets and has a [scripting interface](https://bitcoinarmory.com/developers/python-scripting/).
- [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet) is an online wallet service that has an [interface](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) very similar to bitcoind.  They also have an [API to create wallets](https://blockchain.info/api/create_wallet).

Answer (score 2):

[QOINPro](https://qoinpro.com/) is an online wallet for around 10 cryptocurrencies including Bitcoin, Litecoin and Dogecoin. Additionally, they award coins daily just for being signed up. It's not much, but something while they don't charge anything.

Comment: At first I thought that the promoted service sounded like a scam, because they were promising to give away money for signed up users. However, it appears to be more of a faucet style enterprise. Still, if you consider putting more money there, you might want to do more research.

Answer (score 2):

The wallet that I develop, [Coinomi](http://coinomi.com), has a *core* library (java based) that could be used to host 9 cryptocurrencies at the moment. The private keys are always stored on the client and not on the Electrum servers that it uses to update it's state.

Currently you need to include it in your java project but it is possible to create a JSON API to be language agnostic, it just needs some development.

https://github.com/Coinomi/coinomi-android

Comment: When can we see a JSON API? I code in node.js and would love to build a public node module for people to use